# ngx-mask Do not allow negative value for the currency input

Tags: angular, ngx-mask

I need to block the type of negative value and do not allow to type more numbers than `99,999,999.99` for my input.

Here is the code which I am using for the currency input.

```
<input mask="separator.2" thousandSeparator="," placeholder="Currency">
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Also here is the Stackblitz example.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-mask-currency-input?file=src/app/app.component.html

**UPDATE**

I found the answer to the second part of my question.
now the input looks like this

```
<input mask="separator.2" thousandSeparator="," separatorLimit="10000000"  placeholder="Currency">
```

Now just needs to be blocked the type of `-` character

Comment: I believe the [allowNegativeNumbers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask#allownegativenumbers-boolean) part of the readme answers this question

Comment: @Adam I have used that one. It doesn't work for me. If you have time you can check the stackblitz example in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update on 08.02.2021**

Currently, `allowNegativeNumbers` is working. (ngx-mask version is 11.1.4)

And the input looks like this

```
<input 
   mask="separator.2" 
   thousandSeparator="," 
   separatorLimit="10000000"  
   [allowNegativeNumbers]="false"
   placeholder="Currency">
```

**Update on 01.09.2020**

I have created the directive for blocking the type of negative(`-`) values.

Here is the directive example.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, OnInit, OnDestroy } from "@angular/core";
import { fromEvent } from "rxjs/internal/observable/fromEvent";
import { Subscription } from "rxjs";

@Directive({
  // tslint:disable-next-line: directive-selector
  selector: "[onlyPositive]"
})
export class OnlyPositiveDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  subscriber$: Subscription;

  constructor(private element: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const input = this.element.nativeElement;
    this.subscriber$ = fromEvent(input, 'input').subscribe(
      (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
        if (input.value.includes('-')) {
          input.value = input.value.replace(/-/g, '');
        }
      }
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscriber$.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

**Usage example**

```
<input onlyPositive mask="separator.2" thousandSeparator="," separatorLimit="99999999" [allowNegativeNumbers]="false" placeholder="Currency">
```

After **Adams** Advice I have changed the **keypress** event to the **input** event

**DEMO:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-mask-currency-input?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: This doesn't prevent the pasting of a negative number. To be honest, you shouldn't mess with people's keystrokes - it's very confusing. Let them enter what they're going to enter and provide good validation messages.

Comment: @Adam I agree with you. but in this case, I need to block the type of negative value.

Comment: @Adam also can you clarify why it doesn't prevent the negative number? Do you mean the drag and drop functionality?

Comment: copy a negative number from somewhere and paste it into the field.

Comment: ok, I have fixed the issue. I have changed to the input event. not sure if it is a better way. you can check.

Comment: @Adam Thank you, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 5):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-mask-currency-input-4ssoht?file=src/app/app.component.ts) you can solve with `keypress` event

```
<input (paste)="onPaste($event)" mask="separator.2" thousandSeparator=","  separatorLimit="10000000" [allowNegativeNumbers]="false" placeholder="Currency" class="form-control" (keypress)="isPositive($event)">
```

in component

```
  isPositive(event: any) { return event.key === '-' ? false : true; }
```

and block paste

```
 onPaste(event){
    event.preventDefault();
  }
```

Comment: thanks fo the answer, yeah I thought about that, but I would like to find a more better way if it exists. Otherwise, I will use this or maybe will create the directive with this logic. Thanks Again.

Comment: one word: "paste"